# When does SQL Server warn about an Excessive Memory Grant?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, warning, memory-grant

What are the conditions that produce an *"Excessive Grant"* execution plan warning?

> The query memory grant detected "ExcessiveGrant", which may impact the reliability. Grant size: Initial 5128 KB, Final 5128 KB, Used 16 KB.

#### SSMS

[image: SSMS plan]

[image: SSMS properties]

#### Plan Explorer

[image: Plan Explorer]

#### Showplan xml

```xml
<Warnings>
    <MemoryGrantWarning GrantWarningKind="Excessive Grant"
        RequestedMemory="5128" GrantedMemory="5128" MaxUsedMemory="16" />
</Warnings>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To produce this warning:

1. The **maximum used** memory must be **less than 5%** of the granted memory; ***AND***
2. The query must use the **regular** (not small) resource semaphore

To use the [regular resource semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-resource-semaphores-transact-sql) the query must:

- Have **granted memory over 5MB** (5120 KB, 640 x 8KB pages); ***OR***
- Have a total estimated plan cost of **over 3 units** and not be a *trivial* plan

Server [version requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3172997):

- SQL Server 2014 SP2 (12.0.5000) or later
- SQL Server 2016 SP1 (13.0.4001) or later
- SQL Server 2017 RTM (14.0.1000) or later

Answer (score 0):

### How to Resolve the Warning:

At the time of this writing, Googling this Warning yielded only 7 results.   Just 7.
Luckily one of these links ([sqlservercentral.com](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/performance-question-16/page/4)) had a kind user (by the name of ***DesNorton***)
who had this to say, while helping someone who was running into this same warning:

> *"The query memory grant detected 'ExcessiveGrant', which may impact the reliability.
>  Grant size: Initial 8360 KB, Final 8360 KB,
> Used 40 KB."*
>  - This is related to the table definitions.  SQL
> needs memory to process a query.
>  To figure out how much memory
> to request, SQL uses the meta-data and not the actual data.
>  It
> calculates the size of 1 record based on the field definitions, and
> multiplies that
>  by the estimated number rows that it will get
> back (***based on statistics***).
>  In this case, it estimated
> that it would require 8360KB (or more) of RAM, but due to the actual
> number of records as well as the empty space in the actual records, it
> only required 40KB of RAM.
>  This is a waste of memory, which
> could have been allocated to another query.

Very succintly put.
This immediately made me wonder if Updating the Statistics on my Tables would resolve the issue.
I hunted down any Statistics that had a difference in Rows_Sampled compared to the number of Rows in the Table and Updated them with FullScan on both Columns and Index, like so:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[YourTableName] WITH FULLSCAN, COLUMNS
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[YourTableName] WITH FULLSCAN, INDEX
```

This is, *admittedly*, and overboard approach, but the dev database was small and I was not about to work my way through each and every Stat to find out exactly which one would help my query.

[SqlShack.com](https://www.sqlshack.com/row-mode-memory-grant-feedback-sql-server-2019/) has a great write-up about the "*Row Mode Memory Grant*",
    ***however***, they stop short of offering a solution when you encounter it.