# How to investigate memory grant warnings?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory-grant

Saw this warning from query in plan cache

```xml
<Warnings>
     <MemoryGrantWarning GrantWarningKind="Excessive Grant" RequestedMemory="2751552" GrantedMemory="2751552" MaxUsedMemory="768" />
</Warnings>
```

Does RequestedMemory represent bytes or kilobytes?

How do you troubleshoot what caused this warning?

Comment: They are kilobytes and more info ref by Paul White answer (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228237/when-does-sql-server-warn-about-an-excessive-memory-grant#228238). Can you share your whole execution plan with https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually resultant (though I believe other things can also cause it) from **Cardinality Estimate** issues. You should look at the **Actual Execution Plan** and see if you have any mis-estimates by comparing the **Estimated Number of Rows** total to the **Actual Number of Rows**. If you update your question with the **Execution Plan** (you can upload it to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and link it to your question) then we can give you better direction on the source of your excessive memory grant issue.